# How to store function OR string as value in dictionary (C#)

Tags: c#

I need need to create dictionary whose 
key is string and 
values is either (delegate function OR string).

Because, I want to implement call back mechanism, wherein sometimes I need function for more processing which returns string and sometimes just need to fixed string.

Is there any way to do that in C#?

Thank you

Comment: Lots of anonymous downvotes on the answers to this question.  Does anyone actually have the balls to explain them?

Comment: @Robert, downvoter struck again on Mark and my answers.  Annoying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a `Dictionary<string, Func<string>>`.  This can obviously hold the call back case.  For the non-call back case you can create a trivial lambda to return the hard coded value.

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<string>> m_map;
public void AddValue(string key, string value) {
  m_map[key] = () => value;
}
public void AddValue(string key, Func<string> value) {
  m_map[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: BTW, I have some generic delegate factories which allow a similar approach without lambdas.  Given an identity function, the syntax in VB would be: "m_map(key) = FunctionOf(Of String, String).NewInv(AddressOf IdentityFunction, Value)".  Not too horrible, really.  Unlike lambdas, there's no question of scope.

Answer (score 6):

In the case where you need to have a fixed string you can instead create a function which returns a fixed string. Then in both cases you only need to deal with functions which return strings.

Comment: +1 Based on benchmarks I've done on this sort of thing in the past, this approach will give you the best performance, and it's really simple.

Comment: It's not really the same thing.  For one thing, if your string isn't constant, but is constructed dynamically, you have to have multiple functions, persisting their string data, and then you get into the question of concurrency and the data being changed while it's in the dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A `Dictionary<string, object>` would do the trick, you'll just need to cast the result to `string` or `Func<string>`.

Comment: Upvoted to counter the downvote, and to agree with your answer!  :)

Comment: +1, agree downvote was uncalled for. Solution is completely valid

Answer (score 2):

Declare the value of the dictionary as object.

Comment: Thank you, agreed.  Looks like vote competition getting out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with a string property. That object has the smarts to return the string or call your function to get the string based on its constructor. Then put these in your dictionary Dictionary

```
public class MyCoolClass
{
    public MyCoolClass(Func<string> getString)
    {
        m_getString = getString;
    }
    public MyCoolClass(string s)
    {
        m_string = s;
    }
    public string GetString()
    {
        return m_string ?? getString();
    }
    private string m_string;
    private Func<string> m_getString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example that uses a Dictionary

```
static void Main()
{        
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>();

    dic.Add("A", () => "Hello World");  // Constant lambda
    dic.Add("B", ConstructString);      // Calculated
    dic.Add("C", delegate { return string.Empty; });    // Anonymous delegate
}

static string ConstructString()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```